# How to avoid matching paths that don't have a slash with servlet-mappings?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-mapping

I'm trying to set up a servlet so that any requests for `/foo/*` will go to my `Foo` servlet, except for requests in the form of `/foo/bar/*`, which go to the `Bar` one. However, I want `/foo/bar` to go to the `Foo` servlet, not the `Bar` one. Is there a way to do this with just url-patterns in web.xml?

My mappings:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Bar</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/bar/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I've tried removing the asterisks and trying a few other patterns, but the only way I can see to do this is to have a specific mapping for `/foo/bar`, though it seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using servlet specification v2.5 or above then you could provide multiple *url-pattern* elements for the same *servlet-mapping* like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Foo</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/foo/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/foo/bar</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```